# My SQL code returns no rows for my query

Tags: mysql, sql, view

im trying to write a query that will display for each of my employee member the total the employee was contracted to work, the number of hours classed as overtime they worked and the total pay received by that employee for the financial year 2015 which should run from 1st of april 2014 to the 31st of march 2015 however my query doesnt return any values.
now i have a table that is called payroll that iis connected to the employee table via a foreign key, and it also has a foreign key to reference the timesheet of the employee. i want my output to be something like this:

### END OF YEAR REPORT

BALDROY BARD was contracted for 228 hours, earned £2884.5 basic and £1604.25 in OT.
Total earnings were £4488.75 Pension paid was £145.35

now i have data inserted to these tables that ensures that this query will return at least one record.

just dont understand why it wont return any records. i haven't included "create view" in the code below because i dont want to keep creating the view and deleting it.

```
SELECT  emp_firstname || ' '|| emp_surname || ' was contracted for ' ||  sum(grade_hours) || ' hours, earned £ ' ||sum(Payroll_standard)|| ' basic and £' ||
      sum(Payroll_overtime) || 'in overtime. Total earnings were ' || ( sum(Payroll_overtime) + sum(Payroll_standard)) || ' Pension paid was ' || sum(Payroll_pension) as "END OF YEAR REPORT" 
      from Funtom_employee left join Funtom_payroll on Payroll_emp = emp_ID
      join funtom_grade on grade_id = emp_grade
      where payroll_date between '01-apr-14' and '31-mar-15'
      group by emp_firstname, emp_surname;
```

Comment: Could you please show the tables involved in this?

Comment: hmm how to do that.... erm i can send you picture links

Comment: https://gyazo.com/cc4a7bf37f29fd4029e825e8911432a9
https://gyazo.com/776446c5df6165e55b390054adf26b75

Comment: Like the structure.. so I can figure it out.. it might be the joins, might be the dates that's stored differently.. but I can't know because I don't know the structure of the tables involved.

Comment: there are two links above, shows the tables

Comment: where does Payroll_emp come from?

Comment: ops sorry i forgot to send that one https://gyazo.com/f7ef2a681ff87ca77c45dc4e6524cf25

Comment: Can't really see anything weird.. How are the dates stored?

Comment: what do you mean ? i can show you my insert statements for the payroll table, grade table and employee table

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, that's all I can propose with what you have shown.

```
SELECT ( 
        emp_firstname || ' ' || emp_surname || 
        ' was contracted for ' ||  sum(grade_hours) || 
        ' hours, earned £' || sum(Payroll_standard) || 
        ' basic and £' || sum(Payroll_overtime) || 
        ' in overtime. Total earnings were ' || ( sum(Payroll_overtime) + sum(Payroll_standard)) || 
        ' Pension paid was ' || sum(Payroll_pension) 
       ) as "END OF YEAR REPORT" 
from Funtom_employee 
  left join Funtom_payroll on Funtom_payroll.Payroll_emp = Funtom_employee.emp_ID
  inner join funtom_grade on funtom_grade.grade_id = Funtom_employee.emp_grade
where payroll_date between '01-apr-14' and '31-mar-15'
group by emp_firstname, emp_surname;
```

You should really add a SQL fiddle if it doesn't work

Comment: query runs fine but still no rows selected

Comment: Try running the query with SELECT * .. but still having only the joins in there

Comment: hmmm still no rows selected, i guess somethings wrong with my inserts?

Comment: If you only left the joins theres obviously something wrong with the joins.

Comment: @user2967560 remove one join (and related fields in the select) and test again, if still no rows, put the join back and remove the other join and test again

Comment: any solutions to the joins? coz i dont know how else to join them.

Comment: Right, i removed the grade join, no rows returned, i couldn't do the payroll one, because the whole query runs around it and i got invalid identifier errors

Comment: You can. just remove everything that depends on that join. Or just do a SELECT * for now... doesn't matter what it returns just look if it returns something rn

Comment: @user2967560 you should do the payroll one to ensure it's the one that fails. remove all what's in your SELECT and replace it with * , and remove the GROUP BY that's all.

Comment: guys, i tried what you said and still says no rows returned

Comment: right i tried selecting * from the grade table and joining it to employee and removing everything the depended on the payroll join, and it returned values, it actually returned everything in my employee table

Comment: @MeesKluivers None of them worked still says no rows returned

Comment: The problem is obviously the JOIN with Employee -> Payroll as you stated that the gradle table JOIN works. If you want more help I highly suggest to make a SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/